# Java with FTP and threads

Tags: java

I want a Java class to download files from a Windows machine to a Unix server, and upload files from Unix server to Windows machine using FTP. Both jobs should run synchronously to perform these tasks.I assume here I need two threads.

Could anyone post sample code to perform the above tasks, please?

Comment: @Alonso: i am trying this http://www.unicott.com/java-simple-ftp-connection-example-with-commo,if you have any better approaches. i am not asking complte code write it for me :)

Comment: sorry Raju, but that link didn't work, try to copy & paste some code that you are actually working with, you can edit your post and you will find instructions how to format it in a way that can be understandable... and if you do so I'll remove my downvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) library.

Comment: Do you have any approach to solve this problem.Any sample code really helps me.

Comment: +1 for Commons Net - good library.  @Raju - umm, the example is right there on the page Max provided you.  Heck, it's even called "FTPClientExample.java"

Comment: Commons net is not a good advice for this case FTPClient is not thread safe